# Picker and PickerIOS error in react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to use Picker and PickerIOS in react native and it is displaying correctly, the values are changing properly but my console is blowing up with errors relating to Picker.item and PickerIOS.item. Not entirely sure what I can do about this, seems all the imports are correct from what I know.

```
//imports

import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  Text,
  View,
  ScrollView,
  Switch,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Platform,
  TextInput,
  Picker,
  PickerIOS
} from "react-native";
import styles from "./styles";
import colors from "../../../../Constants/Colors";
import { validateBlank } from "../../../Components/InputValidation/Validate";
import Axios from "axios";
```

```
{Platform.select({
  ios: (
    <PickerIOS
      selectedValue={this.state.businessCountry}
      itemStyle={{ height: 50, width: 250 }}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        this.setState({ businessCountry: itemValue });
      }}
    >
      <PickerIOS.item label="Select your Country" value={null} />
      {this.state.countries.map((country, index) => {
        return (
          <PickerIOS.item
            label={country.name}
            value={country.name}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      })}
    </PickerIOS>
  ),
  android: (
    <Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.businessCountry}
      itemStyle={{ height: 50, width: 250 }}
      onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
        this.setState({ businessCountry: itemValue });
      }}
    >
      {this.state.countries.map((country, index) => {
        return (
          <Picker.item
            label={country.name}
            value={country.name}
            key={index}
          />
        );
      })}
    </Picker>
  )
})}
```

Error message in console, there are two of these related to each picker

[image: Error message in console, there are two of these related to each picker]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was simply a typo. I was using Picker.item and PickerIOS.item rather than Picker.Item and PickerIOS.Item.